# Validation: seems to disregard the fact that alpha characters are not numerical

Tags: php, validation

As per the title, I am experiencing issues in triggering an error in my Binary Calculator when the user enters a rogue input (not 1 or 0) in either of the two calculation fields.

Input should be restricted to 1 or 0. Why when I enter '`a`', does the calculation proceed anyway?

```
$submit = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['submit'])));
$val1 = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['val1'])));
$val2 = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['val2'])));
$val1_length = strlen($val1);
$val2_length = strlen($val2);
$val1 = array_reverse(str_split($val1, 1));
$val2 = array_reverse(str_split($val2, 1));

// Val 1 - Checking
$count = 0; // count variable counts how many times the loop recurs and stops it appropriately
while ($count < $val1_length) {
if(($val1[$count] != 0) && ($val1[$count] != 1) && (is_numeric($binary_input))) { // checks if input is comprised of 0 or 1
    showInputError();   
    exit(); // input does not contain 0 or 1, abort script and do not attempt further calculations
}
$count = $count + 1; // increment the count variable after one successful loop
} // Val1 was fine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It continue becuase `a` is not numeric.
Check this line:

```
if(($val1[$count] != 0) && ($val1[$count] != 1) && (is_numeric($binary_input))) {
```

Which translates to: *if not equal 0 and not equal 1 and is numeric*.
`a`: not equal 0 and not equal 1 and **not** numeric -> proceed.

Change to something like:

```
if(!is_numeric($val1[$count]) || !in_array(intval($val1[$count]),array(0,1)))
```

I don't know what `$binary_input` is, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Where does `$binary_input` come from? I guess you should check `$val1` and `$val2`there and also since you want to display the error if input it not numeric, you should check `!(is_numeric($val1) && is_numeric($val2))`...